# How to I use definitely typed(d.ts) files?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, definitelytyped, google-api-js-client

I am developing an Angular2 web application and I want to incorporate the Google sign in feature. The specific file is this one; [`gapi.auth2.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts).

I have installed it in my project by using this command;

`tsd install gapi.auth2`.

What should I then do next? I'm thinking that I should create a service and in that file I should reference the type definition files;

`/// <reference path="./typings/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts />"`

How do I then start using the methods in the type definition files? What does the syntax look like?

Answer (score -1):

That file [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts) is written in a manner that it pollutes the *global namespace*. So the assumption is that you *add a script tag to `gapi.auth2`* and then just use it like :

```
function test_init(){
  var auth = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'my-id',
    cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    fetch_basic_profile: true
  });
}
```

Note: Always a good idea to see at the test file to see intended usage. In this case : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2-tests.ts